# Can I commit in my branch before pull request is approved?

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

I am working on a branch of a project, say A. I create a pull request for the branch to be merged in master.
Can I commit on my local repository before the pull request is approved.

On this branch I work, I commit and push.

Answer (score 8):

An open pull request will accept new commits until it is eventually merged. **So yes, you can still work on your local branch**, and even push other commits to the same branch, they will then be added to the existing pull request. *(You might need to refresh the page displaying the pull request if you have it already open in your browser, though)*

Of course, once the PR has been merged, new commits on the branch will require a new PR to be merged into your receiving branch.

Comment: What happens if you're waiting for a pull request to be approved. But you want to create a new branch? Should I select the master or the pull request as parent branch?

Comment: @DevDave The pull request is not a branch. The starting point for new branches is an essential part of any workflow. Does your new branch need your previous branch's changes to work on top of? If not, start from the master. But again, this is a matter of choice, so be sure to check with whoever designed your specific workflow.

Answer (score 1):

On Your local machine You can do what ever You want.

But If someone will approve Your PR and merge it and You will try to push Your local commit it will be not possible.

When PR will be not approved/merged You can update it with Your local commit.

When Your PR will be not merged but approved usually when You will push new changes approve will be removed in case of new changes and required review.